# Performing cumsum on multiple columns based on matching index values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I have a dataframe that currently looks like this:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 'Apples 20pk ABC123', 4, 5], [6, 7, 
 'Bananas 20pk ABC123', 9, 0], [1, 2, 'Apples 20pk ABC123', 8, 9]]), 
 columns= ['Serial #', 'Branch ID', 'Info', 'Value1', 'Value2'])

               Serial#  Branch ID    Info                  Value1   Value2
        0         1       2          Apples 20pk ABC123       4        5
        1         6       7          Bananas 20pk ABC123      9        0
        2         1       2          Apples 20pk ABC123       8        9
```

I wanted to groupby the columns: Serial#, Branch ID, and Info to get the cumulative sum of the columns "value1" and "value2". Essentially, it'll only perform "cumsum" if the values under the Serial#, BranchID, and Info columns match.

I thought that I could do something like below, but I'm only getting a df that returns just the index:

```
df[df.columns.difference(['Serial#', 'Branch ID', 
'Info'])].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
# converting other columns(not the three groupby columns) to numeric values 

df_cumulative = df.groupby(['Serial#', 'Branch ID', 
'Info']).cumsum().add_suffix('_cumulative')
```

The end result ideally would be:

```
           Serial#  Branch ID   Info                 Value1_cum  Value2_cum
        0     1       2         Apples 20pk ABC123       4        5
        1     6       7         Bananas 20pk ABC123      9        0
        2     1       2         Apples 20pk ABC123       12       14
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your case , you need overwrite the value back to df , then

```
l=['Serial #', 'Branch ID', 
'Info']
df=df.drop(l,1).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').combine_first(df)
df=df.set_index(l).groupby(level=[0,1,2]).cumsum().add_suffix('_cumulative').reset_index()
df
df
   Serial #  Branch ID  ... Value1_cumulative  Value2_cumulative
0       1.0        2.0  ...                 4                  5
1       6.0        7.0  ...                 9                  0
2       1.0        2.0  ...                12                 14
[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: thank you for your help, it does calculate the cumulative values, but it doesn't take into account the column values (it doesn't groupby) so even though the Branch ID's and Serial #'s are different, it doesn't take that into account. For example (value2_cumulative in your dataframe should ideally be 5, 0, 14 because the second row(serial# = 6) isn't the same as the first and third row (serial#=1)

Comment: @NikTur check your input df , I think that is off you 3rd line is not the same as 1st line

Comment: I just checked, and it seems to be the same. so sorry for the trouble - do you see a difference i'm possibly missing?

Comment: @NikTur from you df your 3rd line is 5,6 and in your print df , it is 1,2 ?

Comment: ah my apologies, I'll fix that!